# An error with Pygame's mixer.Sound.get_volume method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm learning Pygame's mixer module for dealing with music/sfx and when attempting to set the volume for the Sounds, using:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.Sound.set_volume(0.0)
```

It gives me this error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'set_volume' for 'Sound' objects doesn't apply to a 'float' object
```

Which is peculiar considering the documents say it only accepts a float (from 0.0 to 1.0) as an argument. It's also weird considering that the music version, which is the same exact line, just replacing "Sound" with "music," works perfectly fine.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `set_volume()` is supposed to be called on an object, not on the class itself.

You should probably write something like:

```py
my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound.wav')
my_sound.set_volume(0.0)
```

See the documentation of [pygame.mixer.Sound()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) for possible valid arguments.

Comment: That DOES seem to work. But it conflicts with my general, all purpose structure I have now. Not that it can't be reworked. Though, it still doesn't explain why it works with music, just not Sounds when done the way I had it before.

Comment: @Xenko, I think that's just the way the developers of PyGame have designed it. Note that `pygame.mixer.music` is with a lowercase `m` because it's a module and `pygame.mixer.Sound` is with an uppercase `S` because it's a class. This follows common Python style conventions.

Comment: It's also possible to set the volume on the mixer `Channel` directly, rather than the sound.  Ref: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel.set_volume